# left outer join long time execution

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mysql query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(`GuestDailyRate`, 3, 8) as price, a.duration as nights, SUBSTR(b.DebtorEffect, 3 , 8) as debtor
FROM `ARR_2013` a OUTER LEFT JOIN `CMDextras` b 
ON a.`GuestCode` = b.`GuestCode`
WHERE a.`GuestCode`=b.`GuestCode` AND b.DebtorEffect NOT LIKE '%(%' AND a.`GuestRateCategory` = 'BestAvaila' AND
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(a.`ArrivalDate`,'%d-%M-%YY'))=2013
```

Take about 5 minute to show the result

Can help me solve it.

Comment: Why are you using an outer join when you need specific values in the second table? The reason to use an outer join is to get rows with null values in the second table when there's no match, but your `b.DebtorEffect NOT LIKE '%(%'` test will remove all those rows.

Comment: as you already joining two tables based on 
a.`GuestCode` = b.`GuestCode`.. there is no effect of using again the same thing in a where clause as 
WHERE a.`GuestCode`=b.`GuestCode`

Comment: I think MySQL automatically turns this into an INNER JOIN when it sees that test.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `b.GuestCode` and `a.GuestRateCategory`? What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: how to indexes the b.GuestCode and a.GuestRateCategory?

Answer (score 0):

Missing the schema and the order of magnitude row counts, so I can only give some generic hints:

1. Make sure that you have indices on ARR_2013.GuestCode and CMDextras.GuestCode. Aren't you using foreign keys?
2. Do you actually use separate table for each month? This schema will go out of control if you do.
3. The WHERE clause (a.`GuestCode`=b.`GuestCode`) is obsolete, it's already covered by the ON clause of the JOIN.
4. NOT LIKE '%(%': String expansion using LIKE and the % character is generally not very fast. Exact string matches query much faster than "LIKE" queries. The WHERE is eliminating rows that contain '(' --> maybe flag those with a special tinyint column like has_parentheses which you assign when writing the row?
5. STR_TO_DATE: why not use a datetime column, this is a binary format which does range filters way faster.

Comment: 5.) because my arrival date is using string type

Comment: I understand APR_2013.GuestCode and CMDExtras.GuestCode are both FK to <some table>? You could join differently to leverage the GuestCode FK -> APR_2013 a INNER JOIN <some table> st ON a.GuestCode=st.<primary key> OUTER LEFT JOIN CMDExtras b ON b.GuestCode=st.<primary key>.

Comment: As for ArrivalDate: what is your ratio of SELECT to INSERT/UPDATE queries? In most cases, SELECT queries hit WAY more records than INSERT or UPDATE. I recomment parsing the string into a datetime when entering the field into the DB, not in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query. But make sure that join fields should be indexed.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(`GuestDailyRate`, 3, 8) as price, 
a.duration as nights, 
SUBSTR(b.DebtorEffect, 3 , 8) as debtor 
FROM `ARR_2013` a 
JOIN `CMDextras` b 
ON a.`GuestCode` = b.`GuestCode`
WHERE a.`GuestRateCategory` = 'BestAvaila' AND 
b.DebtorEffect NOT LIKE '%(%' AND 
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(a.`ArrivalDate`,'%d-%M-%YY'))='2013';
```

You can further more optimized by below points:

1. ArrivalDate should be date time instead of string.
2. If condition on field GuestRateCategory filter considerable data then you can index this field to get fast results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your query is incorrect. You are outer joining cmdextras records, but then you remove all outer joined records in your WHERE clause. Move `b.debtoreffect not like '%(%'` to the ON clause to avoid that.

```
select 
  substr(guestdailyrate, 3, 8) as price, 
  a.duration as nights, 
  substr(b.debtoreffect, 3 , 8) as debtor
from arr_2013 a 
outer left join cmdextras b on a.guestcode = b.guestcode 
                            and b.debtoreffect not like '%(%' 
where a.guestratecategory = 'bestavaila' 
and right(a.arrivaldate, 2) = '13';
```

Then: It is always horrible to see dates stored as strings in a database. Were they stored as dates you could use a BETWEEN clause which *might* be faster, provided there is an index on arrivaldate and only a small percentage of records lying in 2013. (It's also horrible to see prices and other data being stored as substrings. I recommend to change the whole database design.)

The only equality criteria is guestratecategory. If only a small percentage of rows has the value 'bestavaila', then an index would be needed to use a quick index lookup rather than a full table scan. (BTW: rather than storing strings I would recommend a category table and use its id here instead.)

You join via guestcode. To have this join perform fast, there should be an index on guestcode at least in table cmdextras.

EDIT: One more thought: Your table is named ARR_**2013** and you are checking the arrival date of its records to be **2013** or not? What the heck?